# How to get channel info using youtube API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have been searching through the docs forever trying to find out how I can get a channel's info (subscribers, date created, number of vids, etc.) using the API. I have the channel's ID. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kind of info you're interested in is available via the [`Channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) API endpoint.

Since you did not mentioned which is your programming environment, I'm illustrating my point with a command that you may issue at every GNU/Linux `bash` prompt: a `wget` command line that accesses the endpoint for to produce that channel's [JSON API data](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#resource-representation) on `stdout`:

```
$ wget \
--quiet \
--output-document=- \
--content-on-error \
"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key=$APP_KEY&id=$CHANNEL_ID&part=brandingSettings,contentDetails,id,snippet,statistics,status,topicDetails"
```

Note that `$APP_KEY` is your application key (obtained from Google's developers console) and `$CHANNEL_ID` is the ID of the channel of your interest.